# If my question is lost in oblivion, what could I do to bring it back to the main page where people notice it

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, unanswered-questions, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

If I ask a question which nobody answers for a couple of hours or more, then my question goes off the main page, towards the bottom, and nobody reads it, even though somebody does have a valid answer to it. And nobody is allowed to re-post a question, so what could I possibly do to **legally** bring my question on top again? Does commenting push it to the top? Or maybe editing it?

Couldn't I just post a question and provide a link to my older question saying "Can anybody answer this". Technically that too is a question!

Comment: Jeremy and hammar both answer well, below. *Don't* just post a "can anyone answer this" follow-on question. That'll just get deleted, and get you downvotes for your trouble.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way of bringing extra attention to your question is to add a bounty to it.

Comment: don't you need a high reputation for adding a bounty to your question?

Comment: @Rushil No, all you need is 75 rep or higher.  The minimum bounty is 50 points.

Answer (score 4):

Editing a question will push it back to the top and is acceptable, though you should try to make your edit useful. Posting another question referring to your original one would be frowned upon and closed.

Comment: It could be that no one currently has an answer to my question, even though its as clear as it could be. And it goes down. what edit should make in that case? I just wanna push it back up

Comment: You can't always get what you want - SO gets thousands of questions each day, and not every one of them is going to get in front of every user.

Comment: Yea i guess I'll have to live with that :-(